# Why the data in wishlist can't show

Tags: php, laravel

the product data already store in database but the data cannot show in the wishlist page.How do i solve it??

```
public function  wishList(Request $request)
{
    $products = wishlist::where('wishlist.pro_id','=','products.id')->get();
    return view('wishlist',compact('products'));
}

public function addWishList(Request $request){
    $wishList = new wishList;
    $wishList->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $wishList->pro_id = $request->pro_id;
    $wishList->save();
}
```

this is the wishlist page that i want to show the product..
is it the data cannot get from the database?

```
<tbody>
@forelse($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="{{url('/assets/images/products')}}/{{\App\Product::findOrFail($product->product)->feature_image}}" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
        /*product name*/
        <a href="{{url('/product',$product->id)}}">
        {{$product->title}}
        </a>
    </td>

</tr>

@empty
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <h3>Your WishList Is Empty</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <a href="{{url('/')}}" class="shopping-btn">{{$language->continue_shopping}}</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Does `$products` contain anything? `dd($products)` before returning the view to check that. Also, do you have model relations set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in wishlist query:

```php
$products = wishlist::where('wishlist.pro_id','=','products.id')->get();
```

This will produce sql query

```sql
SELECT * FROM wishlist WHERE wishlist.pro_id = 'products.id'
```

It will not throw mysql exception as 'products.id' is string and I don't think it is the query which you want.

I think you have to join your wishlist on `products` table and then
use `whereRaw` or `where(DB::raw('...')` Query Builder syntax

whereRaw:

```php
Wishlist::whereRaw('wishlist.pro_id = products.id')->get()
```

where:

```php
Wishlist::where(DB::raw('wishlist.pro_id = products.id'))->get()
```

Comment: replace it with the whereRaw?

Comment: Yes, try it and `dd($products)` and see output

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `wishlist` where wishlist.pro_id = products.id), is that the problem from the `use App\wishlist; `

Comment: Have you joined on products table? If not try joining them.
`join('products', 'products.id' , '=', 'wishlist.product_id')` if you have product_id and id your local and foreign key in wishlist table

Comment: thank you for helping the product can show in wishlist!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using @foreach instead of @forelse

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>
        <img src="{{url('/assets/images/products')}}/{{\App\Product::findOrFail($product->product)->feature_image}}" alt="">
        </td>
        <td>
        /*product name*/
        <a href="{{url('/product',$product->id)}}">
        {{$product->title}}
        </a>
        </td>

    </tr>
@endforeach

@else
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
       <h3>Your WishList Is Empty</h3>
    </td>
    </tr>
@endif
```

Comment: It come with an error (syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH))

Comment: That's basically what `@forelse` does - without the errors

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's a bad practice to call a property in the same line you perform a query. Also, in the controller you referred to product id in the Wishlist table as prod_id while you called it as product in the template.

```
<tbody>
  @forelse($products as $product)
  <tr>
      <td>
          @php
           $prod = \App\Product::findOrFail($product->prod_id)) // prod_id not product
          @endphp
          @if($prod)
             <img src="{{url('/assets/images/products')}}/{{ $prod->feature_image }}" alt="">
          @endif
          </td>
      <td>
          /*product name*/
          <a href="{{url('/product',$product->id)}}">
          {{$product->title}}
          </a>
      </td>

  </tr>

  @empty
      <tr>
          <td colspan="6">
              <h3>Your WishList Is Empty</h3>
          </td>
      </tr>
  @endforelse
  <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
          <a href="{{url('/')}}" class="shopping-btn">{{$language->continue_shopping}}</a>
      </td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am not sure if you meant to use $product->title as a part of the wishlist object or the product query you have created on the template. If you meant the product query then you will include the rest of the code in the if condition and use $prod->title